# Is Objective C a pure Object Oriented language?

Tags: objective-c

Is Objective C a pure Object Oriented language ?
Give some strong references if it is ?

Comment: what does "pure" mean in this context? Since Objective-C is a superset of C and you can compile and run straight-up functional C code, seems the answer has to be "no" in any case.

Comment: its not a pure OOP language. its superset of "C" language which means you can have any C language features mixed in with Objective-C code. Strong References ? try the apple documentation.

Comment: Next time do some research before asking your homework questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the Apple [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) guide:

> Objective-C is the primary programming language you use when writing software for OS X and iOS. It’s a superset of the C programming language and provides object-oriented capabilities and a dynamic runtime. Objective-C inherits the syntax, primitive types, and flow control statements of C and adds syntax for defining classes and methods. It also adds language-level support for object graph management and object literals while providing dynamic typing and binding, deferring many responsibilities until runtime.

Thus, one would not consider it a "pure object-oriented language" (and in fact many underlying Core Foundation interfaces are C functions), but you can generally write object-oriented code with it.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's a superset of C. So it can't be a pure object oriented language.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation

> Every object-oriented programming language and environment has a
>   different perspective on what object-oriented means, how objects
>   behave, and how programs might be structured. This document offers the
>   Objective-C perspective.

You can obviously do Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C. Is it a ***pure*** Object-Oriented Programming? I do not think is it possible to answer that question.